# How can I enable audio when window is out of focus

Tags: mass-effect

Lately when playing Mass Effect, I often find myself attempting to multitask between playing the game and doing something else like chatting with a friend.

When I alt tab over to my friend's window, the in-game audio stops. It would be useful if this audio would continue as I could listen to dialog in the background while typing casual conversation to a friend (or something similar).

Is this option available via the ini files?

Or is there something else I can do to make the window think it never lost focus?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible, unfortunately. Whenever the window loses focus the audio will cut out but the game will continue playing. There is also no workaround that I've found that will allow you to make the game believe it hasn't lost focus.